# Javascript object from json file, array inside object is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to access some data which is in a json file. I read the data through AJAX and try to traverse through the data.

Here's my json file.
`{"data":[{"LotNo":"1", "UnitNo":"1"}, {"LotNo":"2", "UnitNo":"2"}]}`

And the function in my html file.

```
function X1(){

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                X2(myObj);   
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.txt", true);
        xmlhttp.send();         
    }
```

And the function in the same file which uses the object.

```
function X2(obj)
    {
       var dataObject = JSON.stringify(obj);
       alert(dataObject.length);                      //Gives me 64 
    }
```

Why does it give me 64?

Why can't I access the data array like this?

```
alert(dataObject.data.length);
```

Or

```
alert(dataObject.data[0]);
```

It gives me the error that 'data' is undefined.

How can I get to the elements of this array?

Comment: You're parsing JSON and then stringifying it again. One of these steps is not necessary.

Comment: Knidly share the content of array it is returning.

Comment: Hi, stringifying the Json, converts the `obj` into a string, and when calling `length` it returns 64, the length of the string. As said by @georg, remove method JSON.stringify.

Comment: It looks you don't need to use Ajax. You can straight-a-way read it from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse parses the given input and attempts to convert it into a JSON object. Which is passed to JSON.stringify inside the X2 method. JSON.stringify encodes the decoded JSON object into a string. The encoded JSON object is 64 characters long instead of 67 characters because JSON.stringify removes the spaces inside the received JSON object.

If you want to access the content in the object remove JSON.stringify. You are able to access properties inside the object since you decoded it already using JSON.parse.

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
console.log(myObj.data[0].LotNo)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Remove JSON.stringify() as it converts an object to JSON.
You are already parsing the json in your ajax call.

```
var dataObject = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Remove this line and try

```
obj.data.length
```